# Reading files from one format and saving as csv format in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. I would like to read LAS files and perform some operation and save the result as .csv file with following piece of code. However, output files are saved as input file format (LAS). I really appreciate any help.

```
library(lidR)

files <- list.files(path= "Input_path", pattern= "*.las", full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)

O <- function(x) {
  las = readLAS(x, select = "xyz", filter = "keep_first -drop_z_below 0")
  data <- as.spatial(las)
  z <- data$Z
  q <- quantile(z, 0.99)
  data1 <- subset(data,data$Z <= q)
  return(data1)
 }

for (f in files) {
  print(f)
  data2 <- O(f)
  write.csv(data2, file = paste0("PATH/", basename(f)))
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to work with the `lidR` API I suggest you to read your `las` file with `rlas`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,file name should be csv

```
write.csv(data2, file = paste0("PATH/",unlist(strsplit(basename(f),"[.]"))[1],".csv"))
```

**EDIT**

if filename has "." middle of name,you can use this method

```
for (f in files) {
  print(f)
  data2 <- O(f)
  s = unlist(strsplit(basename(f),"[.]"))
  filename <- paste0(paste0(s[1:length(s)-1], collapse = "."),".csv")
  write.csv(data2, file = paste0("PATH/", filename))
}
```

Comment: @Sher i have updated the answer,if this solves your issue please mark as accepted answer.happy coding

Comment: use `tools::file_path_sans_ext` to account for "."